# How does java quantifier "?" work?

Tags: java, regex

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[amn]?", "a"));
```

This statement returns true.

But

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[amn]?", "amn"));

System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[amn]?", "adef"));
```

These statements returns false.

Why ?

My understanding about regex quantifier "?" is this.

**Regex:** X?
**Description:** X occurs once or not at all

So the statement "[amn]?" "amn" should return true because a,m,n occurs once.
And similarly in "[amn]?" "adef" a occurs only once and m and n do not occur at all.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Matches works differently then find. Find will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `[amn]?` matches any string which consists of either `a` , `m` or `n` and nothing else. Such as `"a"`, which fulfills this condition.

`amn` and `adef`, however, start with one of these letters, but continue so that the "once or not at all" rule is not fulfilled.

Comment: Hi..I have added a code snippet and that is working. What could be the difference?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal glglgl is right but `?` part mean there can be zero or more match of a,m,n  so it mean no matter what kind of input you give this regex can go infinitely without even checking anything so ? here makes no sense to use.

Comment: ? means **at most 1**. Behavior you describing is expressed by `*` (star). So 2 occurences fails to fullfil "at most 1" rule

Answer (score 1):

The first returns true because `a` is one letter that is either a, m or n.

The others return false because there's not **one** letter, there's 3 and 4 letters.

Even though your letter group contains 3 letters, it will only check for the existence of *one* of them.

Answer (score 1):

Function `matches()` matches the entire string against the regular expression, which means it will return `true` only if the complete string can be matched by the expression, not any sub-sequence. Refer [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

`[amn]?` means that either a or m or n can exists once or not at all. Only cases for which `matches()` will return `true`:

1. "a"
2. "m"
3. "n"
4. ""

All other cases will be given as false.

If you want to find the regular expression in some string, then use `find()` as shown below.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[amn]?");
    Matcher mat = p.matcher("");  //pass amn or adef
    boolean matches = false;
    while(mat.find()){
        matches = true;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
```

Comment: `matches()` and `find()` are two very different functions.

Answer (score 1):

`[amn]` is a group consisting of the characters "a", "m" and "n". 
`[amn]?` means "one of the characters from the group [amn] or no character at all".

`Pattern.matches` tries to match the entire pattern against the entire input string.

If you want the sequence of characters "amn" you could try `(amn)?`, which should mean "the sequence 'amn' or nothing".

Answer (score 0):

? means match current regular expression not greedy